# The current of React UseRef is both the initial value and the element that I'm expecting

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the `useRef` hook to set the ref of a div but it seems as if the value doesn't update once the ref is found. How is the below possible?

[image: current is both 0 AND div]

```
    const SelectDropDown = props => {
    const { helperText, label, ...restProps } = props;
    const [animals, setAnimals] = React.useState('');
    const labelRef = useRef(0);

    const handleChange = event => {
      setAnimals(event.target.value);
    };

     console.log('ref', labelRef);

   return (
   <FormControl>
      <div ref={labelRef}></div>
     <InputLabel id={`label-${label}`}>Animals</InputLabel>
        <MSelect
        autoWidth
        labelId={`label-${label}`}
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={animals}
        onChange={handleChange}
        >
        {options.map(option => {
         return <MenuItem value={option.id}>{option.value}</MenuItem>;
         })}
         </MSelect>
        </FormControl>
      );
   };
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand...what do you mean by "the value doesnt update once the ref is found". Could you give more details on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

the ref isn't assigned and therefore not properly accessible until the component has fully mounted. I ended up using useEffect to get the value.